# WordPress 5.2.1: Embed video is not working. Showing video link on fronted

Tags: videos

I am working on WordPress 5.2.1 new version editor.

I am embedding the video in the content editor. But the link is showing on frontend.

Anyone have a solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: Any JavaScript error in the front end? Have you checked the console?

Comment: No there is no javascript error. I am using fishpig plugin

Comment: Which front-end do you mean - WordPress or Magento?

Comment: Added fishpig plugin in Magento 2. Using WordPress for a blog post on the frontend